# I cannot understand this dot operator

Tags: python, numpy

I don't understand what 5.*inputval[i] means as opposed to not having the full stop/dot

```
outputval=np.zeros(len(inputval)) # Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with zeros
for i in range(len(inputval)):
    if np.random.randn(1)>0.5: # Return a sample (or samples) from the “standard normal” distribution
        outputval[i]=2.*np.sin(2.0*np.pi/5.*inputval[i])
```

Comment: It's not an operator; it's a decimal point. `5.` is a float. `5` is an int.

Comment: In the context of this code the dot (which is a decimal point) can be removed and the results will be identical

Answer (score 0):

In this case `.` is not an operator; it's a decimal point.

`5.` is a float. `5` is an int.

In the expression `2.0*np.pi/5.`, the numerator is a float, so if the denominator was an int it would not affect the result of the calculation.